# How to resolve my promise calls in my case

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise

I was trying to reduce my promise objects in my service. I have something like

```
angular.module('myApp').service('testService', ['Employees','$q',
    function(Employees, $q) {
        var service = {};
        var firstEmp;

        var deferred = $q.defer();

        Employees.query({
            Id: 123
            }, function(objects) {
                firstEmp = objects[0];
                deferred.resolve(objects);
        })


        service.getFirstEmployee = function() {
             var deferredtwo = $q.defer();

            // return deferredtwo.promise;
            //How to solve the double promise defer in my case
            //First promise is wait for the whole employees
            //this one is to return first employee
            deferred.promise.then(function(){
                deferredtwo.resolve(firstEmp);
            })
            return deferredtwo.promise;
        }

        return service;
]);
```

Controller

```
testService.getFirstEmployee.then(function(firstEmployee){
    console.log(firstEmployee) <---show first employee
})
```

I am not sure how to resolve the double promise objects. Can anyone help me? Thanks a lot!

Comment: What's the problem with the solution you have?

Comment: I think you should have to methods one that get all the employees and another that get the employee by id. Having two methods you can test if all the employees are already loaded and get the first one, otherwise query service just for the first one.

Comment: @FelixKling It creates two defer object and I feel like I can get rid of it but not sure how

Comment: @Raulucco I only need a method to get first employee though

Comment: Well, you could change `deferred.resolve(objects);` to `deferred.resolve(objects[0]);` and use `service.getFirstEmployee = function() { return deferred.promise; }`. Is that what you want?

Comment: So why do you need all the others.? If the server will return just everyone resolve the first promise with the first element

Comment: If `Employees` is an angular $resource you could just write something like this `service.getFirstEmployee = function() { return Employees.get({Id:123}).$promise;}`

Comment: @FelixKling and Raulucco I understand, but I need two methods for different purposes. One is for getting all employees, one is for first employee. They serve different purposes across my app

Comment: @BonJon If that's the case, why haven't you demonstrated that in your question? Your example only shows one method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your ultimate objective is just to get the first employee, then you don't need all this "double promise" stuff at all. Just resolve one promise with the first employee:

```
angular.module('myApp').service('testService', ['Employees','$q',
    function(Employees, $q) {

        var pFirstEmployee = $q(function (resolve) {
            Employees.query({ Id: 123 }, function(objects) {
                resolve(objects[0]);
            });
        });

        return {
            getFirstEmployee: function() {
                return pFirstEmployee;
            }
        };
    }
]);
```

If you want two methods - one that returns a promise for all employees returned from the query, and another that returns just the first one from that set, just create a promise for all the employees and chain off of that:

```
angular.module('myApp').service('testService', ['Employees','$q',
    function(Employees, $q) {

        var pAllEmployees = $q(function (resolve) {
            Employees.query({ Id: 123 }, resolve);
        }),
            pFirstEmployee = pAllEmployees.then(function (employees) {
            return employees[0];
        });

        return {
            getAllEmployees: function() {
                return pAllEmployees;
            },
            getFirstEmployee: function() {
                return pFirstEmployee;
            }
        };
    }
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

After the clarification I guess this is what you want:

```
angular.module('myApp').service('testService', ['Employees','$q',
    function(Employees, $q) {
        var service = {};
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        Employees.query({Id: 123}, function(objects) {
            firstEmp = objects[0];
            deferred.resolve(objects);
        });

        service.getFirstEmployee = function() {
            return deferred.promise.then(function(employees){
                return employees[0];
            });
        }

        return service;
]);
```